# Managing Super Admins in a Multi-Workspace Database

Tags: sql, postgresql, authentication, database-design, authorization

I'm designing a database structure for a multi-workspace application where each workspace can have different roles for its users. In my database, I have the following tables:

**`users`**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

**`workspaces`**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE workspaces (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

**`user_roles`**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE user_roles (
   user_id INT,
   workspace_id INT,
   role VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (user_id, workspace_id),
   FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id),
   FOREIGN KEY (workspace_id) REFERENCES workspaces(id)
);
```

I want to create a "super admin" role that should automatically have admin rights in all workspaces. However, I'm concerned that having a super admin with rights in all workspaces could lead to synchronization issues when adding or removing super admin rights.

Here are three possible approaches I'm considering, and I'd like to know which one might be the most efficient or if there's a better way:

1. **Null `workspace_id` for Super Admins:**

   - Create a "super admin" user with a `NULL` `workspace_id`. This would imply that the super admin is applicable to all workspaces.
2. **Separate Super Admin Table:**

   - Introduce a separate table to manage super admins. This table would link users to workspaces where they have super admin rights. it contains the user IDs of super admins and their respective roles.

```sql
CREATE TABLE super_admins (
    user_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    role VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
);
```

3. **Constant Synchronization:**

   - Continuously synchronize super admin rights by adding or removing a user's connection to each workspace when granting or revoking super admin status.

What would be the best approach for managing super admins across multiple workspaces while minimizing synchronization challenges?

Thanks in advance for your insights!

---

Comment: I think this more depend on implementation of cheking rights. Before show some information/menu items or grant to do some actions you should check, if this user has corresponding rights, so your very first point (when you will write logick on the back-side of application) will be check, if this user is superadmin. Why are you talking about synchronization challenges?

Comment: > Why are you talking about synchronization challenges? Because if I have 100 workspaces and I add a super admin, I have to insert 100 entry userid, workspaceid, and right "superadmin". And for each new created wks we have to add existing super admins.

Comment: so, how exactly work your workspaces? Is these separate databases? This is one database but several schemes? Maybe these are even separate clouds?

Comment: @FriendlyDragon Workspace is simply an entity in an application that allows you to restrict access to content (articles, photos, etc.). When a user creates a workspace, he becomes its admin and can invite other users. A super admin is needed to control all workspaces, regardless of whether he created them or not.

Comment: Ok, so looks like you have one databse for all your workspaces. So, I think, it will be good to implement your variant 2 with one superadmin table without any synchronization challenges between workspaces.

Comment: Yes, I was also leaning towards this option, but I don’t like the risk of data desynchronization. We can have a user in the `super_admins` table and at the same time he can be in the `user_roles` table as a regular user.

Comment: For me this is not issue. When you check user's right you can firstly check it in the `super_admins`.... if user already find there, why do you need check this in another tables/locations?